# My hooking doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I'm setting a hook in my GUI application. I want to catch WM_DESTROY message with WH_CBT hook but It doesn't seem work.

```
...

HWND ghWnd = NULL;
HHOOK ghHook = NULL;

...

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    ...

    SetHook();

    ....
}


ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    ...
}

...

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...

    case WM_DESTROY:
        UnHook();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    ...
}

LRESULT WINAPI HookProc(int Id, DWORD wParam, DWORD lParam)
{
    if ( Id == WM_DESTROY )
    {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "I got it", NULL, 0);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(ghHook, Id, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{
    ghHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, (HOOKPROC)HookProc, hInst, GetCurrentThreadId());
    if ( ghHook != NULL )
        MessageBox(ghWnd, L"Hooked", L"Hook!", 0 );
    else
        MessageBox(ghWnd, L"Unable to hook", L"Hook!", 0 );
}

void UnHook()
{
    if ( ghHook != NULL )
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(ghHook);
        MessageBoxA(ghWnd, "Unhooked", NULL, 0);
    }
}
```

When I run the application, I see the message "Hooked" and "UnHooked" when I click to X button (The X symbol on the top right of the window).

But I'm missed the message in the HookProc function.

Can someone explains to me why?

Comment: I mis-read this question.....(was reaching for the spam button...) :)

Comment: CBT hooks require the callback to be in a DLL. Use an accessibility hook.

Comment: CBT can be either global hook or local hook. In my case, It's a local hook so we no need to put them into DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx). The `Id` in a `WH_CBT` hook callback will *never* be `WM_DESTROY`. When a window is about to be destroyed, the `Id` will be `HCBT_DESTROYWND` instead.

If you want to catch the actual `WM_DESTROY` message, use a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook instead.

Comment: When I edit to (Id == HCBT_DESTROYWND), I am stucked in 'I got it' message after the window showup. It mean I can't do anything, the message box appears, I click OK, the message box appears again, I click OK, so on.

Comment: Of course, because the popup dialog that `MessageBox()` shows uses HWNDs like any other UI. When you close the dialog, those HWNDs get destroyed, triggering `HCBT_DESTROYWND` notifications. So don't call `MessageBox()` in your hook, use another debugging approach, like `OutputDebugString()`.

Comment: I added a HWND condition and it works. Thanks for your informations.